# How can I create react element in another?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I building a React app and I ran in the problem that how can I create react elements in another react element depending on the useState?

I created a somewhat simplified example:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Square from './square';

function Chart(props) {

    const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

    function increment() {
        setCounter++;
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={increment()}>More squares</button>
            <div className="container">
                {
                    //I want to create as much <Square number={counter}/>  as the value of counter
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Chart;
```

Comment: What did you try and what exactly is the problem with it? Have you done any research?

Comment: I tried React.createElement("<Square number={counter}/>"); but it did not work.
I checked the documentation too but I did not found the answer.

Comment: Why *would* that work, let alone do what you're trying to? Why mix JSX and createElement?

Comment: I don't know. I'm very young and I'm new to both JavaScript and React. I try everything in my small knowledge to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an array of them. For example:

```
function Chart(props) {
    const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

    function increment() {
        setCounter(oldCounter => oldCounter + 1);
    }

    const squares = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
      squares.push(<Square number={i} key={i}/>)
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={increment}>More squares</button>
            <div className="container">
                {squares}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: You can use an enumerable if you use the counter as the size of an instantiated array. Not faster, but cleaner `Array(counter).fill().map((_, i) => <Square />)`. Or you can do `[...Array(counter)]` instead of `fill`

Comment: I do not understand nothing about this code... 
I'll be happy if it work with the array :)

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at lodash. There is a function `times`, which calls a function n-times.

```
import times from 'lodash/times'
...

function Chart(props) {

...
    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={increment()}>More squares</button>
            <div className="container">
                {times(counter, idx => (<Square key={idx} number={counter}) ) />}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

You can also write this function on your own, if you don't want to import a whole library.

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Square from './square';

export default function Chart(props) {

const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

function increment() {
    setCounter++;
}    

return (
    <div>
        <button onClick={increment()}>More squares</button>
        <div className="container">
            {
               createSquares(counter)
            }
        </div>
    </div>
  );
}

function createSquares(counter){
   const squares = [];
   while(counter){
     squares.push( <Square number={counter} key={counter}/> );
     counter--;
   }
   return squares;
}
```